# CSS Wobble Animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to created a continuous wobble animation on a div id, and its not working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```css
.figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(23, 147, 219);
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset -5px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: wobble 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transition: padding .3s, bottom .3s;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes wobble {
  33% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="figure" ></div>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/nEmJt/1/) what you are looking for? (Note: Un-prefixed standard version of `keyframes` or `animation` is not currently supported by all browsers. You need to use browser specific prefixes like `-webkit-`)

Comment: Works perfectly for me in IE10. Yay IE10 for surpassing Chrome in supported standard (unprefixed) features! :p

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is working , but since it is a sphere you can't notice it rotating , remove `border-radius` to see it. Also use alternate to see better effect

```
animation:wobble 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
```

also use 0% to 100% animation for better result.